# Как с google с помощью скриптов выдрать в папку на рабочем столе все картинки?

Tags: php, javascript, perl

Так же примерно как Марк Цукерберг в фильме социальная сеть выдрал картинки с разных корпусов.

Answer (score 2):

Гы, а вот и можно =)
JS вполне успешно можно распарсить. Там прямо на странице есть 1) картинки вида

```
<img class=rg_i name=Swj3qpAyTftgaM: [...]
```

и 2) есть  div, в котором есть объект, в котором есть параметры. в нашем случае

```
<div id=hd_1 style="display:none">{"Swj3qpAyTftgaM:":["/imgres?imgurl\x3dhttps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_aVPS-c5URrM/Tcm4mscSYmI/AAAAAAAAB9I/q4uHgROHh6I/Bitcoin(2).jpg[...
```

Вот после x3d до следующего x3d есть наш УРЛ. Другое дело, что писать парсер здесь я не буду, ибо это регулярками не возьмешь, а руками по strpos - муторно. Подсказку я дал.

**UPD** Та пожалуйста. php(разрешить внешний file_get_contents):

```
$path = 'путь-до-папки-на-рабочем-столе';
$str = file_get_contents('путь-до-гугла');
$images = parseGoogleImages($str); // по алгоритму выше, ARRAY
$imgNum = 0;
$ext = '';
foreach ($images as $url) {
  $imgNum++;
  $img = file_get_contents($url);
  if (!$img) {
    echo '<b>Error #1</b> with url <b>'.$url.'</b><br />';
    } else {
    $ext = $url;
    while (strpos($ext, '.') !== false)
      $ext = substr($ext, strpos($ext, '.')+1);
    if (!file_put_contents($path.'\\'.$imgNum.'.'.$ext, $img)) {
      echo '<b>Error #2</b> with url <b>'.$url.'</b><br />';
      } else echo 'Url<b>'.$url.'</b> loaded to <b>'.$path.'\\'.$imgNum.'.'.$ext.'</b><br />';
    }
  }
```

Как-то так.

Comment: "а вот и можно" что? тут человек просит не только распарсить но и скачать на хард.

Comment: Мне просто действие "скачать и сохранить" казалось элементарным) Тем более, судя по предыдущим вопросом, у автора локальный сервер. Тем более, что на "как скачать файл через php" гугл выдает уйму решений, а вот "как вытащить из гугла картинки" - вопрос необычный.

Answer (score 0):

На php или perl это вряд ли получиться, там картинки подгружаются с помощью javascript. Можно написать на javascript расширение к любимому браузеру, которое будет собирать адреса картинок, а результат уже передавать скрипту который скачивает по адресам( можно реализовать на пхп или perl).